# taking too much time for large numbers

Tags: c, time-complexity

The factorial of a non-negative integer N, denoted by N!, is the product of all positive integers less than and equal to N. Factorial of any number can be represented in simplest form of its prime factors. e.g. 4!=4*3*2*1= (2^3)*(3^1) Factorials can also be specified by the number of times each prime factors occurs in it, thus 24 could be specified as (3 1) meaning 3 twos, 1 three.
the code which i have written gives answer for small numbers but when the number goes larger the program doesn't return an answer

```
#include<stdio.h>

long fact(long n)
{
    if(n==0)
        return 1;
    else
        return(n*fact(n-1));
}

int main()
{
    long a[10]={0};
    long n,l=0,count=0,i,j,flag;
    if(!scanf("%ld",&n))
    {
        printf("Invalid input");
        goto l1;
    }

    if(n<0)
    {
        printf("Invalid input");
        goto l1;
    }

    n=fact(n);

    while(n%2==0)
    {
        count++;
        n=n/2;
    }

    a[l]=count;
    l++;

    for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {
        count=0;
        j=2;
        flag=0;
        while(j<i)
        {
            if(i%j==0)
            {
                flag=0;
                break;
            }
            else
                flag=1;
            j++;

        }

        if(flag==1)
        {
            count=0;
            while(n%i==0)
            {
                count++;
                n=n/i;
            }
            a[l]=count;
            l++;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
        printf("%ld ",a[i]);

l1:return 0;

}
```

Comment: That is because you are using a recursive solution for calculating the factorial, which makes the call stack grow continuously until it runs out of call stack for really large numbers. Try an iterative version to calculate instead of the recursive form. Example:  
unsigned int iter_factorial(int n) 
  {
      int f = 1;
      int i;
      for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
     {
          f *= i;
      }
      return f;
  }

Comment: Thanks for your response.But i've also tried without recursion but the same problem persists

Comment: You may be causing an overflow of the long type : 100!=9.332622e+157 max value of unsigned long : 2^64-1

You may get an apporximate value using floating point numbers...

Comment: [Don't use Goto!](http://xkcd.com/292/)

Comment: The recursive call is not the issue.  Integer overflow is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can't store the n! value, even in a long as the result grows extremely fast. You should modify your algo: compute the prime factor decomposition of each number from `2` through `n`, and recursively add the decomposition of n-1, n-2...

For example, Suppose you're doing this with 10!. (with `1` omitted)

```
2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 * 8 * 9 * 10.
```

Now, prime-factor *each of these*.

```
2  : 2
3  : 3
4  : 2 * 2
5  : 5
6  : 2 * 3
7  : 7
8  : 2 * 2 * 2
9  : 3 * 3
10 : 2 * 5
```

This means `10!` is equivalent to:

```
2 * 3 * 2 * 2 * 5 * 2 * 3 * 7 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 * 2 * 5
```

Accumulating the count of each *prime* from the terms above we have the following, with `^` denoting exponentiation, not the C operator of XOR)

```
2^8 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 7^1
```

So the answer is `(8 4 2 1)`. Checking our work, we get:

```
2^8 = 256
3^4 = 81
5^2 = 25
7^1 = 7

7 * 25 * 81 * 256 = 3628800
```

My calculator tells me...

```
10! = 3628800
```

So the algorithm is correct. Notice finally, at no time did we need to prime factor any number larger than `n`, in this case `10`.

Note: avoid `goto`s

Comment: Edited for clarity, with sample included.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line in combination with an overflow:

```
for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
```

This works fine as long as the n can be factorized into a large number of small primes, a condition factorials fulfill. No problem with that. The problems start when your factorial cannot be represented as a long anymore. Then the result will be some other number in the value range of long that may have a very large prime factor, or be prime itself.

Now I presume, you are working on a platform where long is 64 bits (you can check by printing the value of `sizeof(long)`), so these large primes can be in the range of 10^18. Even the most modern, fastest hardware can't run your loop through all these numbers in your lifetime. Consequently, that loop will not terminate while you are still waiting for it.

The only way out is to ensure that your calculation does not overflow. You can check after each multiplication if the result divided by one of the factors yields the other factor. If it doesn't, you have an overflow and should exit with an error.

Comment: There is no need to compute large factorials for this problem, and definitely no need to calculate prime factors of enormous numbers. The problem is to generate a list of exponents for the prime-factorization of said-factorials. The example given, 4! == 24 == (3 1), means 2^3 * 3^1, You do not need to compute, nor factor, large factorials to accomplish this (and that is, in fact, part of the intended purpose of the very question itself). By definition a factorial will be made up of both primes and non-primes (which can be factored to primes).

Comment: I clearly state, that the large primes can only occur due to an overflow in the calculation of the factorial; i. e. the number he tries to factorize is not a factorial at all. Hence the possible long runtime. If you use `unsigned char` as a type, 6! will be 208, which has the prime factorization of 2^4 * 13. And 13 is clearly much larger than 6.

Comment: I concur then, and cast my up-vote. In general we both agree his fundamental problem is the algorithm he's chosen (at least it sounds like that). One can easily do this without ever factoring a number larger than `n` for an `n!` question, and it sounds like we both agree on that as well. Finding the prime factor exponent list for 100,000! should be doable in seconds on any decent system.

Answer (score 0):

There are no effective algorithms for factorization of big numbers. 
While probably not the answer you have expected, please take a look at wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization

Comment: His algorithm is effective for factorials, because `n!` has no prime larger than `n`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main obstacles to your approach:

1. A `long`, or even an `unsigned long` isn't big enough to hold the factorial of most numbers. A `long` typically stores 32 bits (though this can vary between architectures), which allows us to store a number less than `2**32 - 1`, which is around 4 billion. 13! is already bigger than that.
2. Too many recursive calls can heavily impact performance due to the overhead in allocating space in the call stack for the function when the compiler doesn't do tail-recursion optimization.

A better solution would be to either use big integers (that can grow to arbitrary size) or to work with double-precision floating-point numbers and using the iterative solution to find an approximate solution.

On another note: usage of `goto` in C is frowned upon. Use `if, else, for, while, switch` instead. Leave that kind of thinking to assembly programming.

Comment: The second point is mute, because you can reach overflow so fast. A function call takes something between 10 and 20 CPU cycles, no factorial he can calculate will take more than a microsecond to calculate.